Passing baseUrl from one config to dependency config
I have my config as
Projects :[
{ name: 'setup', testMatch: 'auth.setup.ts' },
    {
      name: 'e2e-uat',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'https://uat.example.com',
        storageState: '.auth/user.json',
      },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },
    {
      name: 'e2e-canary',
      use: {
        baseURL: 'https://example.com',
        storageState: '.auth/user.json',
      },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },]

but when I run the auth.setup,
await page.goto('/auth/login');

it does not get any baseUrl and hence it becomes an invalid URL.
How can I pass the baseURL from one config to it's dependency configAs here when I run e2e-uat I want to pass baseURL: 'https://uat.example.com' to project setup
and when I run e2e-canary I want to pass baseURL: 'https://example.com' to project setup

Why don't just pass it through command line as required? See below, detailed answer.

You should create a dedicated setup project for each project,
and pass the url using the use property inside each of the setups - because a setup project has it's own tests to execute.
projects: [
    // e2e-uat
    {
      name: "setup-e2e-uat",
      testMatch: "auth.setup.ts",
      use: { baseURL: "https://uat.example.com" },
    },
    {
      name: "e2e-uat",
      use: {
        baseURL: "https://uat.example.com",
        storageState: ".auth/user.json",
      },
      dependencies: ["setup-e2e-uat"],
    },

    // e2e-canary
    {
      name: "setup-e2e-canary",
      testMatch: "auth.setup.ts",
      use: { baseURL: "https://example.com" },
    },
    {
      name: "e2e-canary",
      use: {
        baseURL: "https://example.com",
        storageState: ".auth/user.json",
      },
      dependencies: ["setup-e2e-canary"],
    },
]


Here is how I have solved it until there is a better solution:
Inside my global-setup
async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {

  // get the project name from the command line arguments
  const projectNameArg = process.argv.find((arg) =>
    arg.startsWith('--project=')
  );
  const projectName = projectNameArg
    ? projectNameArg.split('=')[1]
    : config.projects[0].name;

  // get the project configuration
  const project = config.projects.find((p) => p.name === projectName);
  if (!project) {
    throw new Error(`Project ${projectName} not found in the configuration.`);
  }

  // get the base URL and storage state from the project configuration
  const baseURL = project.use.baseURL;
  console.log('=====baseURL=====>', baseURL);
  const storageState = project.use.storageState;

  // other code below...
}

Explanation
First, accessing project name
Here I am trying to fetch the project argument passed in the command line i.e. --project=e2e-canary or --project=e2e-uat
const projectNameArg = process.argv.find((arg) =>
  arg.startsWith('--project=')
);

Second, extracting the project name
From the project argument in above step we try to extract out the project name as:
const projectName = projectNameArg
  ? projectNameArg.split('=')[1]
  : config.projects[0].name;

Third, accessing the project config object
Now we try to fetch the config object that we wrote in our playwright.config.ts file corresponding to the project name that user passed in the command line argument.
const project = config.projects.find((p) => p.name === projectName);
if (!project) {
  throw new Error(`Project ${projectName} not found in the configuration.`);
}


Fourth, finally we access the baseURL
In this setup we try to access the baseURL from config object we just saved in the above step.
const baseURL = project.use.baseURL;
console.log('=====baseURL=====>', baseURL);

